# phpMyAdmin does not show installed themes

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am running phpMyAdmin locally on my XAMPP(lampp). I tried installing some themes in `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/themes` modified their `theme.json` to support my current version (5.2) however, they do not show in the themes list even after ***restarting*** the server multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to put the theme in `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/themes`

If you had the same problem search for the `pmahomme` theme folder. I had two entries one was the one mentioned before and the current directory.